# Why does Stripe.js duplicate options in paymentRequest and PaymentIntent

Tags: stripe-payments

I am following stripe docs to implement [Payment Request Button](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/payment-request-button#verifying-your-domain-with-apple-pay). I am confused why I have to add the amount on the client inside: `stripe.paymentRequest({currency: 'usd', total: {label: 'Demo total',amount: 1099,}})` and also add the amount when creating the client secret from the server side creating a `PaymentIntent`?

Comment: It's probably for consistency, the client can never be trusted but you need to tell the client the value to display to the user, so there will be an equality check that the value the user thinks they're paying is identical to the value generated on the server side, which can be trusted.

Comment: @Martin but what if I want the user to add their own amount, such as a donation. I would have to regenerate a client secret each time?

Comment: I'm not sure, off hand, but this sounds likely. Typically people would set the amount, and then click a button to *confirm* this amount, and in that process the payment request with the amount is set on the server side.

Comment: How would I update price without having to reload the entire page? I tried via an ajax call updating a hidden input field, but it does not update the srtipe amount in stripe.paymentRequest

Comment: In principle, after your AJAX call you would need to retrigger the Stripe JS so the Stripe server side gets retriggered by the ajax and then when that returns to your page the Stripe JS is then retriggered.